# В ВК приложении не работает шаринг фоток

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_share:
            String currentImageUrl = photos.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getSrc_big();
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, currentImageUrl);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}


private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    shareIntent = pagerIntent;
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала, вы шарите не изображение, а ссылку, и указываете тип `"image/jpeg"`

Comment: спасибо, а как правильно вытянуть изображение с ссылки?